Problem with pick bytes out integer variable
I'm trying to extrude 4 char values from one integer. In all my attempts I get same results. The low bytes of high and low word are read correctly, but hi bytes are expanded to int and added bytes are filled with ones. Where am I making a mistake?
Here is example code of my tries. I was compiling it with GCC:
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRINT   printf("b1 %u\n", bb1);\
            printf("b2 %u\n", bb2);\
            printf("b3 %u\n", bb3);\
            printf("b4 %u\n", bb4)

typedef union{
    int integer;
    struct{
        char b1;
        char b2;
        char b3;
        char b4;
    };
}bytes;

typedef struct{
    char b1:8;
    char b2:8;
    char b3:8;
    char b4:8;
}bitfield;


int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("int size = %u\n", a=sizeof(int));
    printf("char size = %u\n", a=sizeof(char));
    bytes in_union;
    bitfield in_struct;
    // values stored in bytes 
    // hword.hi 240 hword.lo 15
    // lword.hi 129 lword.lo 126
    int value = 4027548030;
    
    // #1 solution with union
    in_union.integer = value;
    
    char bb1 = in_union.b1;
    char bb2 = in_union.b2;
    char bb3 = in_union.b3;
    char bb4 = in_union.b4;
    PRINT;
    
    // #2 with pointer to union
    char* uptr;
    uptr = (char*)&in_union;
    bb1 = *uptr;
    bb2 = *(uptr+1);
    bb3 = *(uptr+2);
    bb4 = *(uptr+3);
    PRINT;
    
    // #3 with void pointer to union
    void* vptr;
    vptr = &in_union;
    bb1 = *(char*)vptr;
    bb2 = *(char*)(vptr+1);
    bb3 = *(char*)(vptr+2);
    bb4 = *(char*)(vptr+3);
    PRINT;
    
    // #4 with pointer to value variable
    char* ptr = (char*)&value;
    bb1 = *ptr;
    bb2 = *(ptr+1);
    bb3 = *(ptr+2);
    bb4 = *(ptr+3);
    PRINT;
    
    // #5 with bitfield
    in_struct.b1 = (char)value;
    in_struct.b2 = (char)(value>>8);
    in_struct.b3 = (char)(value>>16);
    in_struct.b4 = (char)(value>>24);
    bb1 = in_struct.b1;
    bb2 = in_struct.b2;
    bb3 = in_struct.b3;
    bb4 = in_struct.b4;
    PRINT;
    
return 0;
}

All gives same results:
bb1 = 126
bb2 = 4294967169
bb3 = 15
bb4 = 4294967280

Expected values:
bb1 = 126
bb2 = 127
bb3 = 15
bb4 = 240


Before expecting too much of your program, turn on more warning options when compiling and fix all of them. example

You need to use unsigned char.

Aside: this // #3 with void pointer to union won't compile in MSVC: *error C2036: 'void ': unknown size shows that you can't use pointer arithmetic with a void* pointer, without non-standard compiler.

Although most processors you'll use are Intel-style little endian, some are big endian. This means using a union like that, b1 might be the low byte, or might be the high byte. It's more portable to mask and shift (e.g i >> 8 & 0xff to get second lowest byte).

int value = 4027548030; doesn't make any sense to begin with. Use a type appropriate for the value assigned to it. What this does is to force an implementation-defined conversion from some large signed type (long/long long) to int. The program is not guaranteed to handle that gracefully but may throw a signal exception.

Two problems in your code:
First:
You are using char type to represent the 4 bytes of int in the bytes union declaration. Each 8 bits can represent a value which may be greater that MAX value a char type can hold on your system.
From C Standard#5.2.4.2.1p2 [emphasis added]

2 If the value of an object of type char is treated as a signed integer when used in an expression, the value of CHAR_MIN shall be the same as that of SCHAR_MIN and the value of CHAR_MAX shall be the same as that of SCHAR_MAX. Otherwise, the value of CHAR_MIN shall be 0 and the value of CHAR_MAX shall be the same as that of UCHAR_MAX.20) The value UCHAR_MAX shall equal 2CHAR_BIT - 1.

It would be better to used unsigned char in place of char type.
Second:
In PRINT macro, passing incorrect format specifier %u to print() for printing char type.
What's happening in your code is that, bb1, bb2, bb3 and bb4 promoted to int and the format specifier you are passing is %u. This is undefined behavior.
From C Standard#7.21.6.1p9 [emphasis added]

9 If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.282) If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Change the bb1, bb2, bb3 and bb4 type to unsigned char and use format specifier is %hhu for printing them.
With these changes, for int value = 4027548030; input, getting this output:
b1: 126
b2: 129
b3: 15
b4: 240

Note that, there are a few more issues in your code but I have pointed out the main ones.

Your supposed improvement to printf("int size = %u\n", a=sizeof(int)); is poor. Instead of recommending %d, it should be printf("int size = %zu\n", sizeof(int));

@WeatherVane My suggestion is for macro PRINT. There are multiple problems in OP's code, I have just pointed out the main issues.

Well, I don't get why your solution outputs negative numbers. In the Staging Ground post, the OP stated that unsigned char solved the problem, which you have not mentioned.

@WeatherVane Note that in my sample output, the value I have used is 2027548030.

I saw that change. The OP's value 4027548030 would be better. Their expected output has non-negative values, not the signed byte values you show,

@WeatherVane Formulated and made correction in the post.

UV for correcting the OP's erroneous bb2 expected value.
